# MySQL сумма последних 10-ти записей колонки

Tags: mysql

Добрый день уважаемые специалисты, помогите с вопросом по MySQL. Допустим есть таблица "сотрудники", в ней колонки "ид (сотрудника)", "зарплата", "дата выплаты" как получить сумму последних 10-ти выплат (по дате) этой таблицы? спасибо.

```
SELECT SUM(зарплата) FROM сотрудники "что дописать?"
```

Comment: а какие-то столбцы типа id или date есть?

Comment: Что такое "последние" записи ? В SQL нет понятий "первый" и "последний" до тех пор пока явно не задан порядок сортировки

Comment: @Peresada могли бы приложить схему таблиц, вы же расписали не особо понятно вопрос, написали дословно - "Сумму последних 10 записей таблицы", однако ответ с выборкой последних 10 записей стали минусить и критиковать. Уточните и перефразируйте вопрос

Comment: @СашаБоричевский Вы видимо не к тому обращаетесь, вопрос задал Игорь Саламов, вряд ли Peresada знает структуру таблиц и прочее, ибо это не его вопрос  ...

Comment: @Mike, извиняюсь, не усмотрел)

Comment: @СашаБоричевский прошу у всех прощения, исправил вопрос, нужны последние 10 выплат по дате.

Comment: Короче, `select sum(зарплата) from (select зарплата from tab order by ДатаВыплаты desc limit 10) x`, а то что то никак не напишут правильную версию ...

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
select sum(зарплата) from (select зарплата from сотрудники order by date desc limit 10)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT SUM(`зарплата`) FROM `сотрудики` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: ORDER BY и LIMIT срабатывают _после_ GROUP BY. А наличие функции SUM() проводит неявный group by. ваш запрос вернет сумму всех строк таблицы

Comment: desc limit 10 выведет сумму всех записей, потому что это limit ограничение строк на вывод, а sum это всего одна строка, то есть даже limit 1, выведет сумму всех строк таблицы

Comment: ну тогда получите данные в код php их просумируйте